# C# Retrieve Values from URL and insert records

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, sage

In my code I have received, by way of a url, a comma delimited list of id's e.g.

```
12,13,14,15,16 etc..
```

I have got these into a string (Tools) which I have Split.

I now need to loop through each value and use it in an insert statement but I have got stuck can anyone help.

The C# below is based on an SDK so it is uses some functions that you may not have seen.

```
string userc = GetContextInfo("User", "UserId");
string tools = Dispatch.EitherField("selectedTools");
tools.Split(',');

string pID = Dispatch.EitherField("key16");

Record recRelTool = new Record("RelatedTools");
recRelTool.SetField("rato_CreatedBy", userc);
recRelTool.SetField("rato_Status", "active");
recRelTool.SetField("rato_server", pID);
recRelTool.SetField("rato_tool", tools);
recRelTool.SaveChanges();
Dispatch.Redirect(Url("1453"));
```

Where the `("rato_tools", tools)` needs to be one of the tool id's in the value I have. I need to loop through until all of the tool id's have been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) does not split your string, it returns an array of strings. You need to enumerate through this array to use one tool id at a time. Try the following:

```
string userc = GetContextInfo("User", "UserId");
string tools = Dispatch.EitherField("selectedTools");
string[] toolIds = tools.Split(',');
foreach (string toolId in toolIds) 
{
  Record recRelTool = new Record("RelatedTools");
  recRelTool.SetField("rato_CreatedBy", userc);
  recRelTool.SetField("rato_Status", "active");
  recRelTool.SetField("rato_server", pID);
  recRelTool.SetField("rato_tool", toolId);
  recRelTool.SaveChanges();
}

Dispatch.Redirect(Url("1453"));
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to assign your split return value:

```
var splitted = tools.Split(',');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

and then you can iterate the collection:

```
foreach(string item in splitted)
{
//do something
}
```